# How to merge rows in SQL based on dates columns if dates are in sequence?

Tags: sql-server, merge

I work with SQL Server and I've got the following table:

```
ID      Res_ID  Start       End
---------------------------------------
5917    9742    2015-08-11  2015-08-11 
5918    9742    2015-08-12  2015-08-12 
5919    9837    2015-09-07  2015-09-07 
5920    9788    2015-09-09  2015-09-09 
5921    9788    2015-09-10  2015-09-10 
5922    9788    2015-09-11  2015-09-11 
5923    9788    2015-09-11  2015-09-11 
5924    9788    2015-10-01  2015-10-01
5925    9788    2015-10-02  2015-10-02
```

I try to merge the rows when the dates are in sequence. In my example, after the query I should get the following table:

```
ID      Res_ID  Start       End
----------------------------------------
XXXX    9742    2015-08-11  2015-08-12 
XXXX    9837    2015-09-07  2015-09-07 
XXXX    9788    2015-09-09  2015-09-11 
XXXX    9788    2015-10-01  2015-10-02
```

I don't really about the final [ID].

I have no idea how to do it...
Could you help me to do this operation?

**EDIT :  The days must be sequential and Start = End in the source table. I updated my example.**

Comment: The end dates are supposed to be 09-10 and 09-11 instead of 10-09 and 11-09?

Comment: @JamesZ Indeed, my bad. I updated it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a gaps and islands problem. Assuming your ranges are always just 1 day long you can do this with row number to calculate the distance from the first day of the group to the row. All those that have the same distance (e.g. deducting the row number from the date ends up into the same day) belong to the same island, otherwise it's a gap:

```
select
  min(id) as id,
  res_id,
  min([start]) as [start],
  max([end]) as [end]
from (
    select
      id,
      res_id,
      [start],
      [end],
      dateadd(day, -RN, [end]) as groupdate
    from
    (
      select
        id,
        res_id,
        [start],
        [end],
        row_number() over (partition by res_id order by [start] asc) as RN
      from
        table1
    ) X
) Y
group by
  res_id,
  groupdate
```

You can check this at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ddaaf/5). I added an extra row to the data that has a gap between the dates to make sure it's not grouped with the rest of the days.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
Min([Start]) OVER(Partition By Res_ID Order By [Start] Asc) as 'Start',
Max([End]) OVER(Partition By Res_ID Order By [End] Desc) as 'End'
FROM sometable
```

This works perfectly. However in order for it to work you cannot select the first ID, which is useless anyway as it's being suppressed in your example.

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/35a07/3)

Comment: This will get you on the right path. Your actually query may involve a select from a select to get exactly what you want.

Comment: @TheMadDBA I've tweaked and tested it, it now works fine.

Comment: I think they want all of the other values as well... and possibly only when the dates are sequential (1 day apart)? But you should have them on the right path with the windowing functions at the very least.

Comment: @Alec Indeed, I updated my question, the days must be sequential only.

Comment: Perhaps you could add something in with datediff from the max start and end on top of this then.

Answer (score 0):

For the exact data set provided in your example, you can use MIN and MAX...

```
SELECT
    DerivedFirstEvents.[ID],
    DerivedFirstEvents.Res_ID,
    DerivedTotalDurations.[Start],
    DerivedTotalDurations.[End]
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        MIN([ID]) AS [ID],
        Res_ID
    FROM
        SampleTable
    GROUP BY
        Res_ID
    ) DerivedFirstEvents
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        Res_ID,
        MIN(Start) AS [Start],
        MAX([End]) AS [End]
    FROM
        SampleTable
    GROUP BY
        Res_ID
    ) DerivedTotalDurations ON DerivedFirstEvents.Res_ID = DerivedTotalDurations.Res_ID
```

However, if a value for your Res_ID appears after a change to another Res_ID, like this...

```
ID      Res_ID  Start       End
---------------------------------------
5917    9742    2015-08-11  2015-08-11 
5918    9742    2015-08-12  2015-08-12 
5919    9837    2015-09-07  2015-09-07 
5920    9788    2015-09-09  2015-09-09 
5921    9788    2015-09-10  2015-10-09 
5922    9788    2015-09-11  2015-11-09 
5923    9742    2015-10-11  2015-10-11  --new line
5924    9742    2015-10-12  2015-10-12  --new line
```

...your result set for Res_ID 9742 will appear to start on 2015-08-11 and end on 2015-10-12, which may not be the desired result.  If this is the case, I think you're going to have a much more complex solution that involves running a cursor through the recordset and inspecting each row to set some variables, then conditionally inserting them into a temp table, then selecting from that temp table when complete.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t

;WITH u ([id],[Res_ID],[Start],[End]) AS ( SELECT N'5917' AS [id], N'9742' AS [Res_ID], N'2015-08-11' AS [Start], N'2015-08-11' AS [End]
 UNION  SELECT N'5918' AS [id], N'9742' AS [Res_ID], N'2015-08-12' AS [Start], N'2015-08-12' AS [End]
 UNION  SELECT N'5919' AS [id], N'9837' AS [Res_ID], N'2015-09-07' AS [Start], N'2015-09-07' AS [End]
 UNION  SELECT N'5920' AS [id], N'9788' AS [Res_ID], N'2015-09-09' AS [Start], N'2015-09-09' AS [End]
 UNION  SELECT N'5921' AS [id], N'9788' AS [Res_ID], N'2015-09-10' AS [Start], N'2015-10-09' AS [End]
 UNION  SELECT N'5922' AS [id], N'9788' AS [Res_ID], N'2015-09-11' AS [Start], N'2015-11-09' AS [End])
SELECT 
    u.[id],
    u.[Res_ID],
    u.[Start],
    u.[End]
INTO #t
FROM u

SELECT
    MIN(id) AS id, [Res_ID],
    (SELECT MIN([Start]) FROM #t AS sub WHERE sub.[Res_ID] = t.[Res_ID]) AS [Start],
    (SELECT MAX([End]) FROM #t AS sub WHERE sub.[Res_ID] = t.[Res_ID]) AS [End]
FROM #t AS t
GROUP BY [Res_ID]
ORDER BY [Res_ID]
```